# "I Like It" and "Rating" in Cross-Site Publishing scenario

Tags: 2013, social, rating, cross-site-publishing

There's a request to implement "I Like" and/or "Rating" functionality in Cross Site Publishing for an item showing as a catalog-item.

There is a single page that displays the detail for the items created in authoring sites. If you enable ratings on the list that contains that page, after you "Like" it, you are liking the reusable page, rather than the item it's showing.

The idea would be to "Like" the item that it's showing, rather than the reusable page.

Is Social tagging/liking/rating functionality supported at all on SharePoint 2013 with Cross Site Publishing?

Otherwise, what are the alternatives?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this ended up being a custom implementation.

We enabled ratings and likings on the list that contained the items in the Authoring site, and then created a custom implementation that applied the likes to the items on that list.

So the detail Page on the Publishing site collection wasn't liked or rated, the items in the authoring sites were.

Comment: Please explain the solution you have implemented above?
Did you see some performance implications? What kind of security role should be given to the people on the authoring site to be able to see the published content? Regards, Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

We didn't want to give users any information about the authoring side. The beauty of xsp is that we can rearrange our authoring side and not disrupt the published version as long as it spits out the same info.

So we created a "CDN" another site with limited permissions (create entry, update, and read) for everyone in our farm. The star ratings are turned on there and some custom code allows them to rate items with the values stored on the "CDN" side.

Overall it doesn't seem to have much performance implications -- compared to all the other SP stuff going on.

The one problem we still face is that the rating doesn't get incorporated into things like most popular or what have you.